# How can I match the page break character in a regular expression?

Tags: grep, regular-expression, escape-characters

Nano calls it `^L`, but of course, typing something like

```
$ grep -v "^\^L" file
```

doesn't work. Its unicode codepoint is 000C. How can I match it in a regular expression?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That seems to be the good old form feed character, described in `man ascii` as:

```
Oct   Dec   Hex   Char
------------------------------------------
014   12    0C    FF  '\f' (form feed)
```

(Not mentioned there, but `^L`'s code is the same 12.)

Then in `bash` any of these should work:

```
grep -v $'\f' file

grep -v $'\cL' file

grep -v $'\x0C' file
```

Comment: That explains why `^L` works to clean up the the screen.  For example, when you're on console, editing a file, and syslog is spamming the console.  Thanks.

Comment: in case anyone else is reading this to find out, kwrite regular expressions accept \f to represent this character

Comment: what is `$'…'` in Bash? never seen that, also does not work for me

Comment: “Words of the form `$'string'` are treated specially. The word expands to string, with backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified by the ANSI C standard.” — [ANSI-C Quoting in Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting)

Comment: Just the third one works for me on Debian 10. `$'\x0C'`

Comment: You are right @Sandburg, in that is confusing. The first 2 have a leading `^` as the question had, to anchor the expression to the beginning of a line. In change the last one finds the form feed character anywhere in the line, not only at the beginning. Unsure why I posted them like that. As the question doesn't mention explicitly the anchoring to the beginning of line, I removed it from the first 2. Thank you for pointing out this inconsistency.